# Converting mysql into PDO format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to convert some old php mysql code into PDO format but am stuck. I've looked at other posts on here but can't quite figure it out.

This is the old code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    // Connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
    mysql_select_db("xxxxx");

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = $_POST['query'];

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
     $array[] = $row['title'];
    }

    // Return the json array
    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

And this is what I've managed to do but think there's something wrong in the "while" part.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
require( "config.php" );
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

// Retrieve the query
$query = $_POST['query'];

// Search the database for all similar items
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%{$query}%'";
$array = array();

while ($row = $sql->fetchAll()) {
    $array[] = $row['title'];
}

// Return the json array
echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

Comment: `$sql` is a string, so when you attempt to call `fetchAll` on it, it results in an error, stating something along the lines of "tried to call a method on a non-object". (I forget the exact wording.) If you have error reporting on you'll be notified as such.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call **fetchAll** on "sql" which is a string.

Now, you could use **query** but i suggest you to use **prepare** instead (for security reason, because you insert POST data).

```
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')");
$q->execute(array($query));

// result contains all returned data
$result = $q->fetchAll();

// or row by row
while($row = $q->fetch())
```

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/pdo.query)

`foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try somehing like this:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
 require( "config.php" );
 $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

 // Retrieve the query
 $query = $_POST['query'];

 //Build Query - Search the database for all similar items
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%{$query}%'";
 $array = array();
 $sth = $conn->query($sql);
 $result = $sth->fetchAll();

 foreach($result as $row){
 $array[] = $row['title'];
 }

 // Return the json array
 echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

=========Updated Answer========

```
//Better alternative
 $query = $_POST['query'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')";
 $sth = $con->prepare($sql);
 $sth->bind_param("s", $query);
 $sth->execute();
 $result = $sth->fetchAll();

 foreach($result as $row){
 $array[] = $row['title'];
 } 
 // Return the json array
 echo json_encode($array);
```

**PS: Best practice is to stick with prepared statements and execute for increased security.**

Comment: If you're going to comment on security, at least make your own answer secure; you're right that prepared statements would be better, but if you're not going to give an answer that shows how to do them, at least you could have escaped `$query`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this:

```
$rows = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE ?")->execute(array('%'.$query.'%'))->fetchAll();

while($row = $rows->fetch()) {
    // TODO: Parse the rows
}
```

Also, try not to use * in your queries, that's not the best practice, it is better to use a column list instead separated by commas, as you do not necessary need to load the values of all columns. select * is less scalable and it might be the source of security vulnerabilities, like accidentally loading the inappropriate column and passing its value to the inappropriate place.